# Is there a Stack Exchange site for discussing agile methodologies?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Pretty much what the top question says, but I would also be interested in people's views on the best place to ask questions about [user stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story) if there isn't a specific site.

Comment: [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) and [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) both have agile tags

Answer (score 5):

We really don't do discussions on any site, just questions and answers.

Keeping that in mind, [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) has a [user-story](/questions/tagged/user-story) tag:

> User story is one of the central concepts of agile software development.

and an [agile](/questions/tagged/agile) tag:

> Agile software development is a group of software development methodologies based on iterative and incremental development, where requirements and solutions evolve through collaboration between self-organizing, cross-functional teams.

So, it may be worth looking at well-received questions with those tags together with the [Software Engineering help centre](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in order to see whether your questions would fit there, too.

Answer (score 3):

Probably [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/).

If it's specifically with respect to software engineering projects then [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) would also be appropriate.

Note that each site has different rules over the types of questions it accepts, and cross-posting is discouraged.